How do you use selection in a List when it has a foreach in inside it
I had a list that was bound to a selection that was working as intended:
@State private var selection: ExerciseName?

 List(exercisesNames,id: \.self, selection: $selection)  { exercisename in
                Text(exercisename.name)     
            }

but I needed to add onDelete functionality so I had to make a ForEach in the list but the problem is now the selection not longer works?
  List(selection: $selection){
              
                    ForEach(exercisesNames) { exercisename in
                        Text(exercisename.name)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                
                    
            }


Since you used id: \.self in your first code snippet, you should do that in ForEach too.
ForEach(exercisesNames, id: \.self) { ... }

List selection is based on the tags of the list rows. The id: parameter (of either List.init or ForEach.init) automatically uses the key path passed to it as the tag. On the other hand, ForEach without an id: parameter uses the elements' id property as the tag.
